# Return elements if they are in two given lists in lisp

Tags: lisp

How can i return elements if they are in two given lists?

Example:

```
L1 = (a b c d e a b c)

L2 = (a d f g k c c)

Result = (a a a c c c c d d)
```

I want to remove elements that arent in both lists and, then, append the resultant lists

Comment: From the Stackoverflow help: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 2):

You can start with a hash table, mapping a list element to a pair, first being elements from the first list, second - elements from the second. Then you collect the elements:

```
(defun common-elements (l1 l2 &key (test 'eql))
  (let ((ht (make-hash-table :test test)) ret)
    (dolist (e l1)
      (let ((pair (gethash e ht)))
        (if pair
            (push e (car pair))
            (setf (gethash e ht) (cons (list e) nil)))))
    (dolist (e l2)
      (let ((pair (gethash e ht)))
        (when pair ; no need to store e when it is not in l1
          (push e (cdr pair)))))
    (maphash (lambda (e pair)
               (declare (ignore e))
               (when (cdr pair) ; we know (car pair) is non-nil
                 (setq ret (nconc (car pair) (cdr pair) ret))))
             ht)
    ret))
(common-elements '(a b c d e a b c) '(a d f g k c c))
==> (A A A C C C C D D)
```

Note that the order in which the list elements are returned is *not* defined.

Comment: I've changed `l1 l1` to `l1 l2` as the parameters of the function and tried it with `(common-elements '(a b c) '(b b c))`

Error returned: *** - NCONC: C is not a list

Comment: consider fixing the code to be a part of your homework. ;-)