# How can I save the result of a dolist in a new list?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to remove, with two given lists, the elements that aren't in both.

The code that I am trying is:

```
(defun remove_odd_ones(L1 L2)
    (cond ((or (null L1) (null L2)) nil)
           ((dolist (x L2) (if (not(member x L1)) (remove x L2))))))


(remove_odd_ones '(a b c c e k) '(a b c p d d n))
```

What I am expecting:  `(a b c c)`

The result I am receiving: `NIL`

Any idea of what function can I use for saving the `dolist` results in a new list?

Comment: `remove` means *remove something from something else*, but from your description *and* from your example it is not clear what is the task that you need to solve. You want to produce the elements present in both lists? But then, why `k` is not present in the result while `d` is present? Both of them are in only one list.

Comment: You're right, I really typed ir wrongly. The expected result would be (a b c) only. Which means, the elements that belongs to L2 and appear in L1 as well.

Comment: Don't you just mean the intersection of the two sets? This being CL of course there is a function for that. However, note that as you have duplicates in your lists you will get duplicates in the result. There is a function to deal with that as well. IF this is homework and you have to write a function with dolist then the syntax of dolist is (dolist ( var list [result-form]) statements). Look in CLHS for an example dolist http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_dolist.htm

Comment: Actually, I need to mantain the duplicates, so the function 'intersect' is perfect for me, thank you so much.

Comment: Well, [`dolist`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_dolist.htm) has a parameter  `[result-form]`, along with `var` and `list-form` used to explicitly tell, what `dolist` will return. Without it, it returns a `NIL`

Comment: You want to remove elements that are not in both. "In both" means (intersection L1 L2); in order to have elements "not in both", you take (union L1 L2) and remove the intersection. Those are the elements you want to remove (i.e. `(k e p d d n)`, keeping duplicates); from what do you want to remove them ? from the whole set of values ? That would be the union again, which inverts the relationship and is the same set as the intersection `(c c b a)`. How do you obtain `(a b c d d)` ? D is not in both sets, so it should be "removed", why do you expect it to be present ?

Comment: The result (a b c d d) that was displayed was a typing error, the result that I was expecting was really (a b c c), I edited the question now, to prevent more mistakes. 
About the function: as David Hodge suggested, the "intersection" function does exactly what I was wondering, I used here in my code and got all the results that I wanted. Thank you all so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return elements if they are in two given lists in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793126/return-elements-if-they-are-in-two-given-lists-in-lisp)

Answer (score 0):

> `(remove_odd_ones '(a b c c e k) '(a b c p d d n))`
>
> What I am expecting: (a b c c)

That is called "set intersection":

```
Lisp> (intersection '(a b c c e k) '(a b c p d d n))
(A B C C)
```

How we can (inefficiently) do that ourselves is:

```
(defun our-intersection (l1 l2)
  (mapcan (lambda (l1-item)
            (if (member l1-item l2)
              (list l1-item)))
          l1))
```

Map over `l1`, collecting those elements which are in `l2`.

The `dolist` function isn't great for this because it isn't functional/applicative; it's a imperative looping gadget. If you want to collect a result list with `dolist`, you have to do that yourself with actions in the body, with the help of additional variables:

```
(defun our-intersection (l1 l2)
  (let ((out nil))
    (dolist (l1-item l1 out)
      (when (member l1-item l2)
        (push l1-item out)))))
```

We define a variable `out` which initially holds the empty list. Our `dolist` walks over `l1`, setting the variable `l1-item` to each element in turn. If `l1-item` occurs in `l2`, it is pushed onto the `out` list:

```
Lisp> (our-intersection '(a b c c e k) '(a b c p d d n))
(C C B A)
```

`dolist` at least lets us specify, vi its third argument, expression which will produce the result value of the form: that's where we placed a reference to `out`.

To get it in `(A B C C)` order, we can replace that reference with a `nreverse` call, like this:

```
(dolist (l1-item l1 (nreverse out))
  ... )
```

This is a common pattern in Common Lisp procedural programming on lists: accumulate results by pushing onto a new local list, and then destructively reverse it with `nreverse` before returning. (This is safe because the list was allocated locally by the procedural code: nothing else in the program knows about the list until is is returned, so the destructive re-arrangement doesn't affect any other function or module).